# Magento BestSeller Cache

Tags: php, magento, caching

I am showing Bestseller on index page of magento. This query takes long time to load. Hence I put following code in the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Bestseller`

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Bestseller extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addData(
            array(
                'cache_key' => 'bestseller_settocache',
                'cache_lifetime'    => 999999999,
                'cache_tags'        => array(
                     Mage_Core_Model_Store::CACHE_TAG,
                     Mage_Cms_Model_Block::CACHE_TAG),
            )
        );
    } 

}
```

I set this block to cache. Now I have a question. Whether magento automatically call this block from cache or whether I need to code something more?

i did try to get block from cache by cache_key but result comes bool(false).

Thanks

Comment: if you have edited this block from core file, then answer to your question is **YES**. It will work. But editing core file is not a good practice. Try to overwrite this block

Comment: Yes I am trying to overwrite works fine thanks